# what is the difference between persistent,preferred and alternate

Tags: html, css

I need to know the difference and the purpose of using `persistent`,`alternate`,`preferred` in linking css in to `html(<link rel="alternate stylesheet">)`.I do not no why this is used and how to use them.

please help.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html

Comment: The specification describes this. If you did not understand it, we need to know what was difficult with it, in order to be able to try explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to give users who "know how to adjust their browsers" options to view your site differently, perhaps a 'large font' version for unsightly folks, pink for girls, or whatever style you may seem fit to target an audience sector.

`Persistent` will always load (use this for your basic blocks, etc) and is default if not otherwise specified

`preferred` will load if requested, will swap with alternate sheet.

`alternate` will be optional by user request (as in the larger font baseline/etc) and will swap out a preferred sheet while the persistent sheet will remain.

read more:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.3.1 & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Correctly_Using_Titles_With_External_Stylesheets

Comment: Are there any browsers left that provide a UI for that?

Comment: Some browsers have something in the `View -> Style`  or  `View -> Page Style` and various other alternatives.   A coded solution can also be done with some JS.   ALA has a write up:  http://alistapart.com/article/alternate

Comment: thanx thats the answer i was looking at :)